# Continuous, unitarily, translation invariant valuations

Tags: integral-geometry

By a theorem of Alesker's, (Hard Lefschetz theorem for valuations, complex integral geometry, and unitarily invariant valuations, J. Diff. Geom. 63 (2003, 63-95), the space $\text{Val}_n^{\text{U}(n)}(\mathbb C^n)$ of continuous, unitarily, translation invariant $n$-homogeneous valuations on $\mathbb C^n$ has dimension $1+\lfloor n/2\rfloor$. A basis of $\text{Val}_n^{\text{U}(n)}(\mathbb C^n)$ is given by the valuations $C_{n,l}$ assigning to every convex body $K$ in $\mathbb C^n$, the number
$$
C_{n,l}(K)=\int V_{2l}\,(\underbrace{\text{Pr}_F(K),\ldots,\text{Pr}_F(K)}_{n \;\text{times}},\underbrace{B_F,\ldots,B_F}_{2l-n\; \text{times}})\text{d}F
$$
where the integral is performed on the grassmanian of $l$-dimensional complex subspaces $F$ of $\mathbb C^n$, $V_{2l}$ is the $2l$-dimensional mixed volume on $F$, $\text{Pr}_F(K)$ is the orthogonal projection of $K$ on $F$, $B_F$ is the euclidean $2l$-dimensional unit ball in $F$, $\text{d}{F}$ is the normalized Harr measure on the grassmanian and $n/2\leq l\leq n$.

As shown by Alesker in the above mentioned paper, Kazarnovskii pseudovolume $P_n$ belongs to $\text{Val}_n^{\text{U}(n)}(\mathbb C^n)$. Let us call *very simple* a valuation $v\in \text{Val}_n^{\text{U}(n)}(\mathbb C^n)$ such that $v(K)=0$ for every convex body $K$ that is included in a complex affine subspace of $\mathbb C^n$ whose (complex) dimension is smaller that $n$. It is well known that $P_n$ is very simple (B. Ya. Kazarnovskii, On the zeros of exponential sums. Soviet Math. Doklady 23 1981, 347-351).

Alesker’s theorem for $n=2$ and $n=3$ implies that the subspace of $\text{Val}_n^{\text{U}(n)}(\mathbb C^n)$ consisting of very simple valuations is $1$-dimensional and is thus spanned by $P_n$.

**Question**: Is this still true for $n>3$?